# Consolidating two data frames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to overlay/consolidate two data frames in python, such that overlapping cells (index,column) get added and uncommon cells preserve the values from original data frame?

This is possible in Excel as explained [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3AE257D2-CA94-49FF-A481-E9FC8ADEEEB5).

For Eg:
I have two data frames

df1 = [image: df1]   df2 = [image: df2]

I want the output to be like

output_df = [image: output_df]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), but in `df1` and `df2` have to be NO `NaN` values, because `fillna` removed them:

```
print (df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).fillna(0).astype(int))
    a    b    c
a1  1    2    0
a2  3  514  123
a3  5  539  134
```

Another solution with [`union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) of both `indexes` and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - works if `NaN` in `DataFrames`:

```
idx = df1.index.union(df2.index)

print (df1.reindex(idx, fill_value=0))
    a  b
a1  1  2
a2  3  4
a3  5  6

print (df2.reindex(idx, fill_value=0))
      b    c
a1    0    0
a2  510  123
a3  533  134

idx = df1.index.union(df2.index)
print (df1.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
       .add(df2.reindex(idx, fill_value=0), fill_value=0)
       .astype(int))
    a    b    c
a1  1    2    0
a2  3  514  123
a3  5  539  134
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3,5],
                   'b':[2,4,6]}, index=['a1','a2','a3'])

print (df1)
    a  b
a1  1  2
a2  3  4
a3  5  6

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[510,533],
                   'c':[123,np.nan]}, index=['a2','a3'])

print (df2)
      b      c
a2  510  123.0
a3  533    NaN

print (df1.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).add(df2.reindex(idx, fill_value=0), fill_value=0))
      a    b      c
a1  1.0    2    0.0
a2  3.0  514  123.0
a3  5.0  539    NaN
```

```
print (df1.add(df2, fill_value=0).fillna(0).astype(int))
    a    b    c
a1  1    2    0
a2  3  514  123
a3  5  539    0 <- replace NaN to 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have gone with your first solution, as Second solution might collapse indices. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I think second solution works too, but it is a bit complicated because works if dataframes (one ot them or both) have `NaN`.